# get value from matrix that have same value in other column in R

Tags: r, get, duplicates

I have matrix that contains 2 columns. First column name is fuzzified and the second is relasifuzzi.

```
fuzzified  relasifuzzi
        1            2
        2            3
        3            5
        5            9
        9            8
        9           10
        9            7
```

I want to make a group like this:

```
fuzzified  relasifuzzi
        1            2
        2            3
        3            5
        5            9
        9            8, 10, 7
```

How can I get like this in R?

Comment: thankyou it's very helpfull for me.. But how can I get the value of length relasifuzzi? I want to compute the mean of the relasi fuzzi when the length of relasi fuzzi is more than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    library(data.table)
    setDT(k1)[,.(relasifuzzi=paste(relasifuzzi,collapse=",")),by=fuzzified]
   fuzzified relasifuzzi
1:         1           2
2:         2           3
3:         3           5
4:         5           9
5:         9      8,10,7
```

## data

```
k1<-structure(list(fuzzified = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L), relasifuzzi = c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 7L)), .Names = c("fuzzified", "relasifuzzi"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: thankyou it's very helpfull for me.. But how can I get the value of length relasifuzzi? I want to compute the mean of the relasi fuzzi when the length of relasi fuzzi is more than 1.

Comment: @BetiEndaryati - instead of using `paste(...)`, use `mean(relasifuzzi)` in the above code to calculate a mean.

Comment: @thelatemail thankyou very mauch. my problem have sold. Thank all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a `data.frame` called "df", try:

```
library("dplyr")

df %>% group_by(fuzzified) %>% 
   summarize(relasifuzzi = paste(relasifuzzi, collapse = ", "))
```

or:

```
library("plyr")

ddply(df, .(fuzzified), summarize, relasifuzzi = paste(relasifuzzi, collapse = ", "))
```